# Binding a nested list , with empty elements, duplicate names and inconsistent structure into one tibble/ R

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, nested-lists

I have a large nested list, that contains other lists, that contain tibbles. After cleaning the elements I am left with a lot of empty tibbles and lists.

Now I want to bring my results into one single Dataframe but I get the error message :

```
Argument x must have names.
```

I am aware that the empty elements screw up my attemps to bind rows, but I can not find a method to drop all empty tibbles.

This is the structure of my data:

```
a<-tibble (1:7,
        letters[7:1])

b<-tibble (1:7)

c<-tibble(.rows=2)




riddle<-list(list(a,b,c), list(list(a,b,c)), list(c),c)

bind_rows(riddle)
```

Please note that this is just a minimized version. So any manual editing or deleting of elements wont work on my original data.

Any solution with purrr would be extra useful! :)

Thanks for any help in advance!!

---

EDIT:

The answer from @akrun solved the upper problem, but I found out that the main issue of my data is the structure of variables with same names.
A common type of character should work.

I've reproduced the error in a slightly changed example:

```
a<-tibble (a=numeric(7),
           b=letters[7:1],
           c=integer(length=1))

b<-tibble (a=integer(length=1),
           b=as.numeric(8),
           c=letters[7:1])


c<- tibble(.rows = 2)




riddle<-list(list(a,b,c), list(list(a,b,c)), list(b,c),c)


map_dfr(riddle, bind_rows)
```

```
Error in `.f()`:
! Can't combine `..1$b` <character> and `..2$b` <double>.
```

Thanks for any ideas

---

EDIT:

Another necessary step was the implementation of `make.unique ()`, as my original data contains duplicate column names, which can not be merged with row.bind, explained and answered by @akrun below.

Comment: Do you need `map_dfr(riddle, bind_rows)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we want to get a single dataset, loop over the `list` with `map` and then use `bind_rows`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map_dfr(riddle, bind_rows)
```

---

If the intention is to remove the datasets that have 0 rows or 0 columns, use a recursive function to check if `all` the `dim` attributes have values greater than 0

```
library(rrapply)
riddle2 <- rrapply(riddle, condition = function(x) all(dim(x)>0), 
     classes = "data.frame", how= "prune")
```

-compare the structure

```
#riddle2
> str(riddle2)
List of 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : tibble [7 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  .. ..$ 1:7         : int [1:7] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  .. ..$ letters[7:1]: chr [1:7] "g" "f" "e" "d" ...
  ..$ : tibble [7 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  .. ..$ 1:7: int [1:7] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ : tibble [7 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  .. .. ..$ 1:7         : int [1:7] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  .. .. ..$ letters[7:1]: chr [1:7] "g" "f" "e" "d" ...
  .. ..$ : tibble [7 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  .. .. ..$ 1:7: int [1:7] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

```
#riddle
> str(riddle)
List of 4
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ : tibble [7 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  .. ..$ 1:7         : int [1:7] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  .. ..$ letters[7:1]: chr [1:7] "g" "f" "e" "d" ...
  ..$ : tibble [7 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  .. ..$ 1:7: int [1:7] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  ..$ : tibble [2 × 0] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 Named list()
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ :List of 3
  .. ..$ : tibble [7 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  .. .. ..$ 1:7         : int [1:7] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  .. .. ..$ letters[7:1]: chr [1:7] "g" "f" "e" "d" ...
  .. ..$ : tibble [7 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  .. .. ..$ 1:7: int [1:7] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  .. ..$ : tibble [2 × 0] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 Named list()
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : tibble [2 × 0] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 Named list()
 $ : tibble [2 × 0] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 Named list()
```

---

For the updated version with different types, we can convert it to single type and then use `type.convert` after binding

```
rrapply(riddle, condition = function(x) all(dim(x)>0),
  f =  function(x) x %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character)),
     classes = "data.frame", how= "flatten") %>%
  bind_rows %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 35 × 3
       a b     c    
   <int> <chr> <chr>
 1     0 g     0    
 2     0 f     0    
 3     0 e     0    
 4     0 d     0    
 5     0 c     0    
 6     0 b     0    
 7     0 a     0    
 8     0 8     g    
 9     0 8     f    
10     0 8     e    
# … with 25 more rows
```

---

If there are duplicate column names, we can make it unique with `make.unique` as `data.frame` needs unique column names.  Also, some functions can return Error when there are duplicate column names

```
rrapply(riddle, condition = function(x) all(dim(x)>0),  
    f =  function(x) 
      {
     # change to unique column names
     names(x) <- make.unique(names(x))
   x %>%  
        # convert all columns to character if there
        # are mismatch in column types in any list elements
        mutate(across(everything(), as.character))
     },      classes = "data.frame", how= "flatten") %>% 
     # bind the flattened list of data.frame/tibbles to single dataset
    bind_rows %>%
     # do the column type conversion 
     type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I made a minor change in my example, but your methods still apply. Unfortunately I am still getting the error message for my original data. I will have to play arround with your approach for a bit and come back. Thanks!

Comment: @arnemaa i guess you have modified the `c` to attribute for rows to be 2 without data, thus the `nrow(x) > 0` would still be TRUE because it is checking on that attribute.  We could use either `nrow(x) >0 & ncol(x) >0` in the second solution or use `all(dim(x) >0)` as in the updated one based on your data.  For the first solution, it is still working with your unnamed example though

Comment: The issue withing my original data results from different variable types. Some of them are double, integer, or numeric but share the same name. Thereby row_bind / map_dfr does not work. I previously thought that I had worked around this, but your approach made it clear to me that this is still the root of the problem. Unfortunately I have not found a way to change the type of varaibles accross an unevenly nested list yet, so I might have to reopen a new thread

Comment: @arnemaa You can recursively convert everything to `character` and then read it with map_dfr

Comment: Could you give the semantics of the function that does what you've described? As I am not familiar with rraply this was my best best attempt, but it only gives me back a list off all integer values.  `og_data<-rrapply(og_data, condition = function(x) is.integer(x)==TRUE, classes = "ANY", how= "prune")` I could in theory work with that and edit everything manually, but there must be a more effcient way.

Comment: I have edited a more precice example that produces my error in the original question

Comment: Thanks again. I get the error for my original data: `! Can't transform a data frame with duplicate names` , but I guess we are close!

Comment: @arnemaa I am guessing you have duplicate column names which are not allowed in data.frames

Comment: How would you implement `make.unique()`? I guess that should do the trick

Comment: @arnemaa that would be `rrapply(riddle, condition = function(x) all(dim(x)>0),
  f =  function(x) {names(x) <- make.unique(names(x)); x %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character))},
     classes = "data.frame", how= "flatten") %>%
  bind_rows %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)`

Comment: It worked!! This saved me so much time! rraply seems to be very useful so I ll have to work more with it. Thanks a lot and happy holidays